# How to apply affine transform so that it works well with all transforms including translation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, affinetransform

For some reason `imtransform` function ignores translation part by default.

If I add additional space with `XData` and `YData` as it said in manual, I will handle only simple cases (i.e. translation only).

So, how to apply full-featured affine transform in Matlab?

```
I = imread('cameraman.png');
imshow(I);

% does not translate
xform = [1 2 0; 2 1 0; 100 0 1];
T = maketform('affine',xform);
I2 = imtransform(I,T);
figure, imshow(I2)


% translates but cuts some portion of an image
xform = [1 2 0; 2 1 0; 100 0 1];
T = maketform('affine',xform);
I2 = imtransform(I,T,'XData',[1 size(I,2)+xform(3,1)],'YData',[1 size(I,1)+xform(3,2)]);
figure, imshow(I2)
```

Comment: I think you are confusing the 'XData' command with the 'axis' command.  [Steve's blog on Matlab image processing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/07/07/spatial-transformations-translation-confusion/) has some excellent examples.

Comment: Article looks not to say something new to me. And I still don't understand, how to perform transformations in all cases. Note: I don't want to DRAW image on screen correctly, I want to have it transformed in memory correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found I should apply transform to image range too.

After that I can decide, what to do if an image corner is not at the beginning of coordinates.

```
I = imread('cameraman.png');
XData=[1 size(I,2)];
YData=[1 size(I,1)];
imshow(I);

xform = [1 2 0; 2 1 0; 100 0 1];

T = maketform('affine',xform);
[XData1, YData1] = tformfwd(T, XData, YData);
if XData1(1)>1
    XData1(1)=1;
end
if YData1(1)>1
    YData1(1)=1;
end
I2 = imtransform(I,T,'XData',XData1,'YData',YData1);
figure, imshow(I2)
```